# React Native - BVLinearGradient - 'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native

I am running my React Native app in the iOS Simulator, and I am trying to use `BVLinearGradient`.  I followed all of the instructions in the GitHub ReadMe, but I am receiving an error related to `BVLinearGradient`.

In the developer console, I am seeing:

```
Warning: Native component for "BVLinearGradient" does not exist
```

When I run directly from XCode, I see:

```
'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found` (in BVLinearGradientManager.h)
'React/RCTView.h' file not found` (in BVLinearGradient.h)
```

What is happening here?

Comment: If you're using < 0.40, make sure you use react-native-blur@1.2.1

Comment: I'm using > 0.40

Comment: did you run `react-native link react-native-linear-gradient`

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same issue a few days ago. The problem is that React is not linked yet when building the app. Try this:

Go to **Product** => **Scheme** => **Manage Schemes...** => Click on your app Scheme (usually the first one on the list) and click **Edit** => Go to the **Build** tab => Uncheck *Parallelize Build*

Then Click on the **+** sign to add a target => Search for *React*, select the first target called **React** and click on **Add**

[image: Add React to targets list]

Then select **React** in the targets list and drag it up to be first in that list.

Then go to Product => Clean and build your project again.

That should help.

Comment: React. in  Not going to Click event Add (React Option Not selected And Add Button Coming) how to add another option Any one help me

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you simply do not have the library linked correctly. A couple things to check:

- Make sure your in your `package.json` you have `"react-native-linear-gradient": "2.0.0"` (you may have perhaps forgotten `--save` when you installed?
- If you recently updated to `>0.40` you might really want to clean your Xcode project (Product --> Clean) and it might help to clean your build folder too (Product --> hold option on your keyboard  --> Clean Build folder)
- Check your build scheme, it looks like the library might not be able to find `React` meaning perhaps it hasn't been built yet. This can be the case if you are NOT installing via Cocoapods. Follow the steps found in this comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11721#issuecomment-270672904

Good luck! Hope this helps.

Comment: I started a new project, using RN 42.  I have the most up to date version of the package installed.  I will look into that comment.  Does this mean I should be using Cocoapods?

Comment: Nope, you don't need Cocoapods. Then you should follow the directions under the manual installation on the `react-native-linear-gradient` library. It can be a hassle to get the libraries linked correctly sometimes.

Comment: Yes I am still getting the error :(.  I am trying to do it with my Podfile now but I am getting a new error: [!] Unable to find a specification for `Yoga (= 0.42.0.React)` depended upon by `React/Core`

Comment: You'll need to add this `pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :inhibit_warnings => true` to your Podfile, just make sure it directs to your node_modules folder correctly

Comment: You can't add the "React" target to the scheme, despite what your linked comment says.